# R function to subset DF by top X most frequent occurances of categorical variable?

Tags: r, filter, categorical-data

I have a ~150,000 observation DF of 23 columns, one of which is "groupname" which includes over 1000 different group names.

How can I subset this dataframe to only include the group names of the top 10,25 or 50 most frequently occurring group names?

Thanks in advance